# Authentication or Impersonation in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, impersonation

I have a mvc web application hosted on iis and SharePoint installed on another machine. The Web application read the directory on SharePoint. How can I authenticate all the request coming from the machine on which mvc web application is deployed on SharePoint? or how can I impersonate all request to a service account which has permission to access the SharePoint?

Please provide a link with some information how can I achieve this as I am new to SP 2013